# Onclick event won't trigger url direct

Tags: php, wordpress, button, onclick

I have a working snippet that I want to tweak. I am trying to change the OnClick event (see altered code), but I can't get the OnClick event to trigger.

**What works:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_button_function', 10 );
function my_button_function() {
  global $product;
  echo ' <button type="button" class="back-button" onclick="history.back();"> Back to overview </button> '; 
}
```

**Altered code** (I don't get any errors but the button just doesn't do anything)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_button_function', 10 );
function my_button_function() {
        global $product;
        echo '<button type="button" class="back-button" onclick="window.open("https://www.lanacreations.nl/products");"> Back to overview </button>'; 
    }
```

**I also tried to put the onclick event into a seperate function:**

```
function myClickFunction() {
  window.open("https://www.lanacreations.nl/products");
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_button_function', 10 );
function my_button_function() {
    global $product;
    echo ' <button type="button" class="back-button" onclick="myClickFunction()"> Back to overview </button> ';
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last block of code is invalid, it's conflating PHP and JavaScript. Your second block of *would* work, but it appears you just have a syntax error. You've got double quotes inside your attribute that's encapsulated with double quotes - so your HTML is breaking, and is actually being interpreted as:

```
onclick="window.open(" https:="" www.lanacreations.nl="" products");"="">
```

So to fix that, you can replace the double quotes inside your JavaScript function with single quotes, provided that you [Escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) them. If you start a string with `'`, you can "escape" a single quote with a forward slash `\'` to tell PHP "I want you to actually PUT a single quote here, NOT treat this like the end of the string".

Try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_button_function', 10 );
function my_button_function() {
    global $product;
    echo '<button type="button" class="back-button" onclick="window.open(\'https://www.lanacreations.nl/products\');"> Back to overview </button>'; 
}
```